# Kotlin Gradle DSL to exclude acceptance test when running unit tests

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I using the gradle kotlin DSL and I need to exclude my acceptance tests when running `build` or `test`. Currently I have

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
   exclude("*acceptance*")

}
```

Which doesn't work. The acceptance test is executed, it is not excluded.

I also need to configure my `build.gradle.kts` to run my acceptance tests. At the moment I have an `acceptance` directory which is under is under `src/test/groovy` and I have created a acceptanceTest task as per the documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests). The acceptance test is not run with this configuration.

```
sourceSets {
    create("acceptance") {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
    }
}

val acceptanceImplementation by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.implementation.get())
}

val acceptanceTest = task<Test>("acceptanceTest") {
    description = "Runs Acceptance tests."
    group = "verification"

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets["test"].output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets["acceptance"].runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter("test")
}

tasks.check { dependsOn(acceptanceTest) }
```

Comment: The acceptance test is executed, it is not excluded.

Comment: Can you give more context? What's the name and location of the acceptance test you want to exclude? Where are your unit tests located and how are they named?

Comment: I'm using the Spock framework for both unit tests and acceptance tests. the location of the tests is 'src/test/groovy'.  The unit tests follow the same package structure source code. I have added another package called 'acceptance' which is where the acceptance tests are. The acceptance tests have the word acceptance in the file name i.e. 'MyAcceptanceSpec'

Comment: If I change my acceptance test name to `MyAcceptance` and add `includeTestsMatching("*Spec")` in a filter block, the acceptance test isn't run but the unit tests are. Still not clear why the example in my original post doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `exclude` pattern uses Ant-style path matching, so, in order to exclude all tests in a directory named `acceptance`, you need to do:

```
exclude("**/acceptance/**")
```

However, doing so for all tasks of type `Test` as you've shown will never run the acceptance tests. You need to skip it only for unit tests, which is the task named `test`.

To run the acceptance tests, you'll use the same path pattern with `include` inside the `acceptanceTest` task.